# weird symbol is shown up in the eclipse for .java file

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Suddenly some weird symbol is displayed on top of my class file in eclipse and no suggestions are working in that class file.

Symbol displayed on top of the java file --> **{}**

Please find the below image for more details

[image]

Arrow marked in the RED is the file which is acting weird
Arrow marked in yellow  does not have the symbol and it is working as expected

Comment: don't post images instead of code (certainly not if you forget to post the image)

Comment: why is this tagged with javascript and selenium?

Comment: Apologies, i have updated the image
and i am using javascripting for IDE[eclipse].

Comment: Looks like you have opened the file with a different editor. Right click on the file in Package or Project Explorer and see what the 'Open With' menu has selected.

Comment: @greg-449 : Thanks a lot for your solution, i have been struggling to find out the root cause. now its fixed. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You get weird symbols there when your java file is not a part of src folder package. You need to keep all your java files under source folder. or if this folder needs to be added as a src type, then do the same under project properties.